# Nikah and Walima

Tags: nikah

I had my nikah done last June, but now my husband and I want to live together but my mother-in-law is not allowing us to do so and my in-laws are not letting our walima happen this year.
My parents talked to them about the walima to be done this August but my in-laws are avoiding them.
I live away from my parents because of my job and my husband is also in the same city away from his parents and I am alone in this city.
What should I do and what are we supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Sunni view as per the Qur'aan and the Sunnah.

The word NIKAH means marriage. If your nikah is done, there's nothing to stop you from joining your husband. But I do hope you really mean nikah and not a mere proposal. The nikah covers the marriage contract and both parties have agreed to proceed in their lives and married people.

I know this is a common custom amongst many Asian folks but this is not correct.  Once you complete the nikah, you are married.

If your folks insist on a delayed waleema and staying away from each other, that's a personal issue.

And Allaah knows best!

Comment: Yes the nikah is done but rukhsati is pending. Are we still allowed to live together

Comment: @user5065 Yes you are allowed to live together. Rukhsati is strictly a cultural thing and it has nothing to do with Islam. In Islam you do the nikkah and you are married and you can live together. Allah as well as your local law has given you permission. Your parents do not overrule Allah's permission.

Comment: According to my knowledge, *walima* is generally held after the *rukhsati*. And *walima* does not have to the next day or the second day. Although it is recommended to have a *walima* for must.